# having trouble using greather/less than operator.... (beginner)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that goes through a list of 10 user input integers to test if they are greater than number input by the user.

my code:

```
def displaylarger():
   global n
   global inLst
   count = 0
   greater = [i for i in inLst if n < i]
   print(greater)
```

This is for a class that requires me to use these numbers for the user input
['23', '67', '8', '90', '56', '45', '38', '69', '30', '68']

I am suppose to test them against '40'

but when I put in the numbers, this is what comes out:
['67', '8', '90', '56', '45', '69', '68']

I don't understand why my code keeps checking the third element as greather than 40.

I've tried using the if and else statements, but they produce the same results.
I am honestly so confused why the third element keeps popping up in the output.

Comment: Those are strings, not numbers.

Comment: Please do not use global in functions, use arguments, and return the result. it makes better and reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the strings into ints. This can be done as seen below:

```
strNum = "1"
num = int(strNum) # Turns string to int
```

So change your code to this:

```
def displaylarger():
   global n # N needs to be int
   global inLst
   count = 0
   greater = [int(i) for i in inLst if int(n) < int(i)]
   print(greater)
```

**Lastly to add some context in Python when your compare two objects of the same type that's defined in the `def __gt__(self, other)` method of the class. Read more into it here (https://www.journaldev.com/23511/python-string-comparison)**

Comment: As `n` seems user input, better convert to`int` too ;)